# The negation of an implication.

Tags: real-analysis, logic

I have the following statement and I'm not sure what the negation is. The statement is:

If $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function satisfying some regularity assumptions $(R1)$ then we have $$\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)\ge 0.$$

I think the negation should be:

If $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function satisfying some regularity assumptions $(R1)$ then we have $$\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)< 0.$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Negotiation is what you do when you want to buy a house. You negotiate the price. What you mean is probably the **negation** of the statement.

Comment: @AsafKaragila ops! Thanks for your comment. edited

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Recall that $p\rightarrow q$ is equivalent to $\lnot p\lor q$. Therefore the negation of the implication is the same as negating the disjunction. Using DeMorgan laws we have: $$\lnot(\lnot p\lor q)\equiv\lnot\lnot p\land\lnot q\equiv p\land\lnot q.$$

Therefore the negation of "If one then two" is "one and not two".

Comment: A small question. What is the difference in this case between "If one then not two" and "One and not two"? My stated negation is "If one then not two".

Comment: $$p\rightarrow\lnot q\equiv\lnot p\lor\lnot q\equiv\lnot(p\land q)$$ Your suggested negation is true if either one or two are false; which is not the negation of an implication.

Comment: Now you lost me :) I want to proof that the full statement above, call it $q$ (i.e. $q=u\to v$), is equivalent to another statement $p$. For the direction $q\implies p$ I want to use contrapistion, i.e. $\neg p\implies \neg q$. So I need to know what $\neg q$ is. I do not exactly understand your last comment "...is true if either one or two are false; which is not the negation of an implication." Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: In his original answer, Asaf shows you how to derive the *negation* of $p \rightarrow q$ starting from the equivalent form $\lnot p \lor q$. So the conclusion : "Therefore the negation of 'If $p$, then $q$' is '$p$ and not $q$' ".
Regarding your comment about " What is the difference between 'If $p$, then not $q$' and '$p$ and not $q$' ?" he pointed out that the first one (i.e.$p \rightarrow \lnot q$) is NOT the *negation* of $p \rightarrow q$.