# What does negation affect and what does it not?

Tags: logic

[image]
This question came up on Keith Devlin's course on mathematical thinking. I was wondering whether the negation would apply to all terms in this sentence? As in, does the negation apply to 'all' and 'badly' but not the adjective and noun 'foreign cars'?

Comment: @SahibaArora There is no need for MathJax in this question, and it is perfectly well typed.

Answer (score 2):

If by 'terms' you mean predicate terms (like 'being well-made' or 'being foreign made') or subject terms (like 'cars'), then the answer is **none**.

You **never** negate subject terms or predicate terms.  Likewise, you **never** negate objects or predicates.  The only thing you ever negate are **sentences**.

This is because sentences express claims that can be true or false, and that is something we can negate.  But an object is ... well, an object.  What would it mean to 'negate an object'?! Sometimes I see the expression $\neg x = y$ interpreted as $(\neg x)=y$, which supposedly would mean something like 'the object that is the negation of $x$ equals $y$' ... Which is really just unsyntactical and meaningless.

The same goes for predicates. That is, when we write $x \not = y$, we don't mean something like $x (\neg =) y$, but $\neg (x=y)$; again, *the only thing you negate are sentences.*

Answer (score 1):

I make it the last of the options, let $C$ denote cars, $F$ mean foreign-made and $B$ mean badly made

I think the original sentence can be written
$$
\forall C ( F \rightarrow B)
$$

So its negation is
$$
\exists C ( \neg (F \rightarrow B) )
$$

And we can re-write the negation of the implication as follows, see eg. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/633602/435819)
:
$$
\exists C (F \wedge \neg B) )
$$

Which in English could be 'There is a car that is foreign and not badly made'.

Answer (score 0):

It does not apply to 'foreign cars'. Even if you think about it 'logically', rather than mathematically, you can notice that a proposition on 'foreign cars' says nothing about a proposition on 'domestic cars' (and vice-vers) -- they're disjoint sets.

Answer (score 0):

This sentence is of the form $(\forall x)(\varphi(x))$. The negation of this statement is $(\exists x)(\lnot\varphi(x))$. This translates to the statement that there exists a foreign car which is well-made. That is, assuming that well-made is the negation of badly-made.